# Query to ignore rows which have non hex values within field

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Initial situation**

I have a relatively large table (ca. 0.7 Mio records) where an nvarchar field "MediaID" contains largely media IDs in proper hexadecimal notation (as they should).

Within my "sequential" query (each query depends on the output of the query before, this is all in pure T-SQL) I have to convert these hexadecimal values into decimal bigint values in order to do further calculations and filtering on these calculated values for the subsequent queries.

--> So far, no problem. The "sequential" query works fine.

**Problem**

Unfortunately, some of these Media IDs do contain non-hex characters - most probably because there was some typing errors by the people which have added them or through import errors from the previous business system.

Because of these non-hex chars, the whole query fails (of course) because the conversion hits an error.

For my current purpose, such rows must be skipped/ignored as they are clearly wrong and cannot be used (there are no medias / data carriers in use with the current business system which can have non-hex character IDs).

Manual editing of the data is not an option as there are too many errors and it is not clear with what the data must be replaced.

**Challenge**

To create a query which only returns records which have valid hex values within the media ID field.

(Unfortunately, my SQL skills are not enough to create the above query. Your help is highly appreciated.)

The relevant section of the larger query looks like this (xxxx is where your help comes in :-))

```
select  
    pureMediaID
    , mediaID
    , CUSTOMERID 
    ,CONTRACT_CUSTOMERID
            
    from
    (
        select concat('0x', Replace(Ltrim(Replace(mediaID, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')) AS pureMediaID
        --, CUSTOMERID 
        , *
        from M_T_CONTRACT_CUSTOMERS

        where mediaID is not null
        and mediaID like '0%'

        and xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    ) as inner1
```

**EDIT:** As per request I have added here some good and some bad data:

Good:

```
4335463357
4335459809
1426427996
4335463509
4335515039
4335465134
4427370396
4335415661
4427369036
4335419089
004BB03433
004e7cf9c6
00BD23133
00EE13D8C1
00CCB5522C
00C46522C
00dbbe3433
```

Bad:

```
4564589+
AB6B8BFC.8
7B498DFCnm
DB218DFChb
d<tgfh8CFC
CB9E8AFCzj
B458DFCjhl
rytzju8DFC
BFCtdsjshj
DB9888FCgf
9BC08CFCyx
EB198DFCzj
4B628CFChj
7B2B8DFCgg
```

Comment: Please show some sample data, good and bad.

Comment: `mediaid` or `MEDIAID` - please pick one and stick with it. Inconsistent usage makes your code more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939324/how-to-check-if-varchar-strings-are-not-hexadecimal  where it sez --  Starting from SQL Server 2012, you can employ TRY_CONVERT()

Comment: @SMor: thanks for pointing this out - jep - I agree.

Comment: `where not mediaid like '%[^0-9A-Fa-f]%'`

Answer (score 1):

After I did upgrade the compatibility level of the SQL instance to SQL2016 (it was below 2012 before) I could use try_convert with same syntax as the original convert function as donPablo has pointed out. With that the query could run fully through and every MediaID which is not a correct hex value gets nicely converted into a null value - really, really nice.

Exactly what I needed.

Unfortunately, the solution of ALICE... didn't work out for me as this was also (strangely) returning records which had the "+" character within them.

**Edit:** The added comment of Alice... where you create a calculated field like this:

```
CASE WHEN "KEY" LIKE '%[^0-9A-F]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 end as xyz
```

and then filter in the next query like this:

```
where xyz = 1
```

works also with SQL Instances with compatibility level < SQL 2012.

Great addition for people which still have to work with older SQL instances.

Answer (score 0):

An option (although not ideal in terms of performance) is to check the characters in the MediaID through a case statement and regular expression

Hexadecimals cannot contain characters other than A-F and numbers between 0 and 9

```
CASE WHEN MediaID LIKE '%[0-9A-F]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I would recommend writing a function that can be used to evaluate MediaID first and checks if it is hexadecimal and then running the query for conversion

Comment: This is getting closer - but when I put this as a filter in the where clause, the following record is also returned: "4564589+" where there is the "+" character which of course lets the query run into an error.

Comment: You could try it the other way around i.e. CASE WHEN MediaID LIKE '%[^0-9A-F]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ... it should notice the + sign is not part of the regular expression

Comment: You *have* to write it the other way around. The plus character was just treated as a wildcard leaving other characters to match the valid set.